# Is there a neater way to fill a JTable with a web page's attributes retrieved from XPath?

Tags: java, swing, xpath, jtable, tablemodel

I'm creating a a web page scraper. I'm attempting to fill a JTable from data on the page, retrieved using XPath. I want the data for a single row put into an array.

```
{"Name","Phone","Address","City","State","Postal Code","Link"}
```

I retrieve the webpage into a string to be parsed. There are no \n's(Sorry, I don't know the proper word for this. New lines?)

[image: Screenshot of program]
The array represents the data in a column. The way I want to do it is to make it so it retrieves the individual data row that row, then inserts it into the array, then it's placed into the  JTable. Then the array is set to null, the process is repeated.

Another option which I **REALLY** do not want to have to deal with would be placing all of the individual cells into array lists for each column, then do a while loop. The issue with this is that a entry might return empty, which would mean the indexes might not be perfectly synced.

I'm a rather "new" programmer, with about 6 months of experience of actually doing most things on my own. I'm still working on building my methodology, however here I'm stuck.

I'm wondering what would be the best solution in this situation, there's probably a better solution that I have not thought of.

This is not a raw code problem, rather a flow problem.

It's messy, yes. However it was **very** easy for me to crawl using Google Docs's xPath & ImportXML functions.

Here is what I would put in the cells:

**Name:**

```
=importxml("http://www.yellowpages.com/[location]/[type]","//a[@class='no-tracks url ']")
```

**Address:**

```
=importxml("http://www.yellowpages.com/[location]/[type]","//span[@class='street-address']")
```

**Phone:**

```
=importxml("http://www.yellowpages.com/[location]/[type]","//span[@class='business-phone phone']")
```

I didn't do the others, however I know it's possible.

Removed the HTML example for privacy reasons, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate an Object that best represents the data (array).  Use the data from the array to construct the object and add the object to the table model...

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postalCode;
    private String link;
    public Data(String[] data) { 
        name = data[0];
        phone = data[1];
        address = data[2];
        city = data[3];
        state = data[4];
        postalCode = data[5];
        link= data[6];
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
}
```

Create a table model that is capable of taking advantage of this data object...

```
public class MyDataTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Data> dataList;

    public MyDataTableModel() {
        dataList = new ArrayList<Data>(25);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        String name = "??";
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                name = "Name";
                break;
            case 1:
                name = "Phone";
                break;
            case 2:
                name = "Address";
                break;
            case 3:
                name = "City";
                break;
            case 4:
                name = "State";
                break;
            case 5:
                name = "Postal Code";
                break;
            case 6:
                name = "Link";
                break;
        }
        return super.getColumnName(column);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Object value = null;
        Data data = dataList.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = data.getName();
                break;
            // Other case statements per column...
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void add(Data data) {
        dataList.add(data);
        int index = dataList.size() - 1;
        fireTableRowsInserted(index, index);
    }
}
```

Once you have a new `Data` object, use this models `add` method to add it to the model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll have to check this out tomorrow. (It's 10:50PM where I'm at. I have school tomorrow.)

Comment: use DefaultTableModel instead of, there no reason to helt two models

Comment: Sorry I'm rather new to using xPath, I don't understand how I could incorporate xPath into this.

Comment: Do you have an example of the xml

Comment: I'm actually crawling Yellow Pages. I was able to successfully do it via Google Docs using ImportXML & XPath, however I want to make a Java program that does it. I have edited my post to include an example.

Comment: Okay, there are twos I can think of for you to proceed, you could something like [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) which will allow you to parse the HTML as if it was XML, allowing you to use xPath, or [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) which is HTML DOM with it's own search mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you for linking me to JSoup, it looks useful and I believe I can get the 'job' done with it.